# how can I force display in another language

Tags: windows

I'm currently using a Vista computer with settings in French.

For creating help files and taking screen snapshots purposes, **I need to force windows to display start menu, control panel etc... in English, and later German, Spanish...**

Of course, I can't afford to buy several computers! Is there a way to change the system language display?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 now comes with language packs (see [video](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/language-packs))

Apparently the same is true [for Vista](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/How-do-I-get-additional-language-files)

Comment: Yes, one can change that property. But unfortunately you'd better pee in a violin! It would have same result... On Vista at least.

There's even a button within the blue welcome screen (shown when you close session and re-open), with "En" or "Fr" etc. You can click and change and... Again, nothing happens. Wether you shut down or not.

Comment: As far as I know that button is just for the keyboard layout (try putting FR and then typing the numbers and you'll see). Unfortunately I cannot give you precise instructions as I use Linux.